# Howto rewrite URLs with two nginx as reverse proxies to gunicorn/Django

Tags: nginx, rewrite, reverse-proxy, django, gunicorn

I have a Django application, deployed with gunicorn on port 8000, on a VM with a backend nginx, port 80, on the same VM. The nginx config is:

```
    location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
    }

    location /static/ {
    }
```

On the frontend side, there is another nginx, port 443, translating the user visible URLs `https://myserver.com/myapplication/` into the internal `http://myvm/`. The nginx config is:

```
    location /myapplication/ {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://myvm/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
    }
```

While I can access any URL such as `https://myserver.com/myapplication/` without problems, the links in the Django application are all missing the `/myapplication/` path component. What's wrong with my nginx setups? Is it the fronted or the backend that is wrong?

Comment: Your application don't know anything about `/myapplication/`. You should configure it

Answer (score 0):

The frontend configuration is OK, but the backend needed a change:

```
    location / {
            ...
            proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /myapplication;
    }

    location /myapplication/static/ {
            alias /path/to/myapplication/static/;
    }
```

The relevant bit was setting `SCRIPT_NAME` which seems to be interpreted by Django.

It would still be nice to have a solution, where the backend does not need to be configured with the path, maybe by passing the script name from the frontend to the backend and having some magic for the static files. But hey, it works!